# Make UIImage Smaller than UIImageView to see background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to make it so that I have a UIImageView with an image, regardless of its size beforehand, so that the background color of the UIImageView shows up as a border around the UIImage.

I tried making the UIImageView with an image and then shrinking the bounds but that didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler approach is to setup the border on the image view's layer:

```
UIImageView *imageView = ... // create image view with image
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1; // Size as desired
imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]; // use your own color
```

You need to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to make this work.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I didn't even think of that. Thanks a bunch buddy.

Comment: The border grows inside the UIImageView. You will cover the UIImage by doing this

Answer (score 1):

Rmaddys suggestion of creating a border of the amd colour is not bad. However, that would only work if the background is of the same colour overall.

More options I could think of: 
1) Make your image smaller. I am talking obout the png (or other) file. But select an appropriate mode for the UIImageView so that the image will not be streched. 
2) Include a border with alpha 0.0 within your image file. 
3) Embed your UIImageView within another UIView with blank background. So that the UIImage is nested in the UIImageView as usual but the UIImageView is smaller now. Place this on the center of a new UIView that has the sizse that you UIImageView used to have.